# Operator "publishOn()" and thread affinity in Reactor Project

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I don't clearly understand from documentation how `publishOn()` (or `observeOn()` in case of RxJava) operator works in terms of thread affinity. I thought that this operator guarantee that any subscriber will be processed in the same thread, but following example has broken my understanding:

```
Flux<String> started = ep.publishOn(scheduler);
Flux<String> afterStateUpdate = started.doOnNext(e -> {
    System.out.println("STATE UPDATE : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    state.add(e);
}).share();
afterStateUpdate.subscribe();
ep.onNext("1");
ep.onNext("2");
ep.onNext("3");

afterStateUpdate.subscribe(e -> {
    System.out.println("MAIN SUBSCRIBER : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
});
ep.onNext("4");
ep.onNext("5");
ep.onNext("6");
```

As result I see following output:

```
STATE UPDATE : 12
STATE UPDATE : 12
STATE UPDATE : 12
STATE UPDATE : 13
MAIN SUBSCRIBER : 13
STATE UPDATE : 13
MAIN SUBSCRIBER : 13
STATE UPDATE : 13
MAIN SUBSCRIBER : 13
```

It means that "state updater" had been working in thread 12, but when second subscriber subscribed "state updater" started working in thread 13.

So, the question is how in this case I can guarantee thread affinity for my subscribers?

Comment: can you precise which `Processor` you use (you seem to be using a Processor) and which scheduler? (I'm assuming `DirectProcessor` and `Schedulers.single()`, but just in case)

Comment: I use EmitterProcessor.

Comment: And scheduler like this `Schedulers.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found only one way to be 100% sure that one subscriber uses the same thread. It's to create a pool of single schedulers like this:

```
Scheduler[] schedulers = new Schedulers[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  schedulers[i] = Schedulers.newSingle();
}

public Flux<T> wrapIntoSingleThread(Scheduler scheduler) {
  return this.flux.publishOn(scheduler);
}
```

And then for every subscriber take a one scheduler from this pool: `wrapIntoSingleThread(schedulers[i++ % schedulers.length]).subscribe(...)`

If anyone know other way to provide thread affinity - please correct me.

Comment: There is no abstraction of thread affinity in JVM. If you really need to manipulate thread affinity, use JNI or a Java library wrapped JNI core.

Comment: Note, the author is enquiring about thread affinity, not about CPU core affinity.